# Google API Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth

I have registered my application's client ID and client secret 
for my web application running on GoogleAppEngine.
My app uses the Directory API to sync user info with Google Apps.

Sending API request and response works OK, 
but some users can't get a response from the server.
API's response is:

> redirect_uri_mismatch

Is there a restriction on the number of users when using Directory API ?
The user has an administrator role in the Google Apps domain.

Comment: what did you enter as the redirect uri in Google developers console?

Comment: I entered uri "http://appname.appspot.com/oauth2callback"
and my problem is , why some user get response "redirect_uri_mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the scheme for URIs: http or https

Comment: I entered URI as "http://appname.appspot.com/oauth2callback". But some user's request and response looks fine , but another user API Request fail with "redirect_uri_mismatch".